# Oracle SQL Developer: stop script running if error

Tags: sql, oracle, error-handling, oracle-sqldeveloper

The default behaviour of SQL Developer is to keep running the subsequent commands in a script even though an error is encountered.
Is it possible to have it stop, or ask the user whether to continue or not (e.g. like in SQL Workbench)?

Comment: Check this http://www.orafaq.com/forum/index.php/mv/msg/176936/533997/#msg_533997

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Developer supports the SQL*Plus commands [`whenever sqlerror`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/WHENEVER-SQLERROR.html#GUID-66C1C12C-5E95-4440-A37B-7CCE7E33491C) and [`whenever oserror`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/WHENEVER-OSERROR.html#GUID-A52F926F-D6EC-434E-9C7E-CFDB76422E94).

These allow you to stop processing when the script hits an issue.

For example, if I run this:

```
select * from dual
where  ;

select * from dual;

whenever sqlerror exit
whenever oserror exit

select * from dual
where  ;

select * from dual;
```

The output is this (notice the final select doesn't happen):

```
SQL> select * from dual
  2  where  ;

Error starting at line : 2 in command -
select * from dual
where  
Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 7
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
SQL> 
SQL> select * from dual;
DUMMY   
X        


SQL> 
SQL> whenever sqlerror exit
SQL> whenever oserror exit
SQL> 
SQL> select * from dual
  2  where  ;

Error starting at line : 10 in command -
select * from dual
where  
Error at Command Line : 11 Column : 7
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Good info, thx! Note that this still doesn't handle unrecognized statements, e.g. `grogu * from dual` or `-select * from dual` (note the "`-`" character in front of "`select`").

Comment: So it doesn't; I'm not sure if there's a way to handle these